# Convert many time observations columns to a single block of time

Tags: r, time

I have a dataframe that contains the number of times a user hit a website broken down in one-hour increments.  R reads each of these columns in as discrete integer vectors.

```
   month user.nm X0.1 X1.2 X2.3 X3.4 X4.5 X5.6 X6.7 X7.8 X8.9 X9.10 X10.11 X11.12 X12.13 X13.14 X14.15 X15.16 X16.17 X17.18 X18.19 X19.20
1 Apr-2013 6688393    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2 Apr-2013 6694392    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0      1      1      0      0      1      0      0      1      0      0
3 Apr-2013 6695127    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
4 Apr-2013 8466767    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2
5 Apr-2013 8466929    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
6 Apr-2013 8469145    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     2      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  X20.21 X21.22 X22.23 X23.24
1      0      0      0      1
2      0      0      0      0
3      1      0      0      0
4      0      1      0      0
5      0      0      0      0
6      0      0      0      0
```

I would like to either modify the existing data frame or create a new one such that all 24 columns are treated as one block of time on a continuous scale, with 24 buckets for each hour range. I would like to see if there are any regular trends in user login time throughout the day, and would like to use `ggplot` to either facet this data out by month, or overlay a series of line graphs for each month on one graph.

I've attempted to use melt to create a new dataframe, but it doesn't quite give me what I want:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot)    

test=melt(stackdata)
        .t=ggplot(data=test, aes(x=variable, y=value, color=month))
        .t+geom_line()+
          geom_jitter()+
          facet_wrap(~month, ncol=4, nrow=3)+
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Again, this is because each variable in the dataset is not one large, subdivided block of time.  Not sure how to tackle this problem from here, and would love suggestions.

sample data is below:

```
stackdata=structure(list(month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("Apr-2013", "Aug-2013", "Dec-2013", "Feb-2013", 
"Jan-2013", "Jan-2014", "Jul-2013", "Jun-2013", "Mar-2013", "May-2013", 
"Nov-2013", "Oct-2013", "Sep-2013"), class = "factor"), user.nm = c("6688393", 
"6694392", "6695127", "8466767", "8466929", "8469145", "9611057", 
"9612737", "9614602", "9615501", "9615784", "9615874", "9616110", 
"9618319", "9619088", "9619598", "9621017", "9621742", "9622336", 
"9624374", "9626854", "9627467", "9627624", "9629276", "9630734", 
"9631364", "9631860", "9632476", "9635781", "9635959", "9641708", 
"9643094", "9645186", "9645401", "9745784", "9754198", "9866781", 
"9867611", "9868751", "9869108", "9870583", "9870726", "9938726", 
"9941106", "9941399", "9941473", "9941772", "10001415", "10003807", 
"10005825", "10013098", "10013225", "10015143", "10016062", "10020754", 
"10022365", "10024519", "10025576", "10026220", "10035739", "10035819", 
"10051839", "10054951", "10054984", "10062088", "10068499", "10074245", 
"10075246", "10077086", "10079384", "10680141", "10686895", "10694897", 
"10697647", "10699389", "10699429", "10704583", "10711494", "10712441", 
"10715234", "10716488", "10720706", "10720791", "10720823", "10728749", 
"10801017", "10807796", "10811707", "10816089", "10821019", "10825304", 
"10830839", "10833479", "10833571", "10834836", "10839626", "10841820", 
"10846461", "10849478", "10855264", "10858750", "11005529", "11020252", 
"11020885", "11032718", "11033697", "11036794", "11040344", "11047885", 
"11050965", "11052554", "11069521", "11073718", "11075499", "11079738", 
"11093749", "11095438", "11095559", "11097178", "11110244", "11550287", 
"11589571", "11683596", "11699090", "11705401", "11709313", "11709654", 
"11717437", "11719508", "11772681", "11779464", "11781654", "11789565", 
"11794224", "11809622", "11815102", "11851768", "11900155", "11931084", 
"11957879", "11972086", "12001983", "12007772", "12009821", "12011698", 
"12016362", "12016670", "12038636", "12056747", "12057451", "12059322", 
"12096520", "12101444", "12118773", "12127176", "12159551", "12165289", 
"12177700", "12178152", "12182494", "12197023", "12225175", "12235523", 
"12242927", "12254486", "12266022", "12286648", "12323873", "12403763", 
"12408314", "12414114", "12420854", "12457521", "12466982", "12537659", 
"12544328", "12557309", "12558588", "12600078", "12669593", "12669837", 
"12674687", "12677883", "12689243", "12691517", "12694967", "12695845", 
"12701494", "12854160", "12869058", "12869828", "13281780", "13400065", 
"13400593", "13401168", "13401493", "13402162", "13402454", "13403431", 
"13403910"), X0.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 23L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), 
    X1.2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L), X2.3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L), X3.4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), X4.5 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 4L, 0L), X5.6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L), X6.7 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L), X7.8 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 13L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L), X8.9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    5L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 22L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 
    1L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X9.10 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
    4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    8L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    2L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), X10.11 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    5L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
    X11.12 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 17L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X12.13 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X13.14 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X14.15 = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), X15.16 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 1L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L), 
    X16.17 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    7L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L), X17.18 = c(0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 20L, 3L), X18.19 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L), X19.20 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 12L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L), X20.21 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L), 
    X21.22 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X22.23 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L), X23.24 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("month", 
"user.nm", "X0.1", "X1.2", "X2.3", "X3.4", "X4.5", "X5.6", "X6.7", 
"X7.8", "X8.9", "X9.10", "X10.11", "X11.12", "X12.13", "X13.14", 
"X14.15", "X15.16", "X16.17", "X17.18", "X18.19", "X19.20", "X20.21", 
"X21.22", "X22.23", "X23.24"), row.names = c(NA, 200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df <- melt(stackdata, id.var = c("month", "user.nm"))
df$hour <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "^.*\\.", "", df$variable))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = hour, y = value)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 24, by = 4))
```

[image]

Comment: yes, absolutely.  I see that you compute a new hour column, which is interesting.  I'll play with stat_summary, as I haven't had much of an opportunity to use it.

Comment: The new hour column is not strictly necessary. I just thought it was easier to format a numeric x axis, rather than an axis with "X0.1" et c. You may also aggregate your values outside `ggplot`, e.g. `df2 <- aggregate(value ~ hour, data = df, mean)`.

Comment: that's interesting.  one last question:  what's the need for the `group=1` argument?

Comment: I added `group = 1` to quickly; it's often used together with `geom_line` (see e.g. [**here**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_%28ggplot2%29/), but apparently not needed for `stat_summary`.